# VueJS computed prop not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Preface

I'm trying to use a piece of data as a prop in a child component. I need to modify this prop a bit to get the data that I want. My problem is that that computed prop isn't reactive.

### How my data looks

```
{
    "SomeItem": "0",
    "DynamicItem1": "0",
    "SomeOtherDynamicItem": "0"
}
```

This is my initial state, which I transform to a object via JSON.transform(). The important part is that there can be any number of dynamic items. There can be DynamicItem10 and so on.

### What I'm doing with the data

This data lives in my parent component's data object. Whenever I get update from my websocket, this is how I change the data:

```
Vue.set(this.nodes, node, value)
```

I got this from the reactivity in depth document in vues docs. This is supposed to make dynamically added properties to a data object reactive, AFAIK. This works correctly, because I can see the data being updated correctly in the console.

Next, I pass this data to my child component via props, like this:

```
<Step1 :nodes="nodes" style="grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 1" />
```

In my child component, I first assign the props to my data component, as per [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-property-not-updating/21148) thread:

```
data() {
    return {
        localnodes: this.nodes
    };
}
```

Because I need to do some filtering, I use a computed property for that:

```
computed: {
    width_nodes: function() {
        var widthnodes = {};
        for (var node in this.localnodes) {
            if (node.includes("DynamicItem")) {
                Vue.set(widthnodes, node, this.localnodes[node]);
            }
        }
        return widthnodes;
    }
}
```

### The problem

I expect this computed property to update whenever the corresponding data in my parent component changes. That is not the case however. I can see the changed data in the vue devtools, but the computed property doesn't reflect those changes. This seems to be directly related to the reactivity change detection caveat, because if I add for example DynamicItem2 to my initial data, it gets updated correctly.

### EDIT: How I used width_nodes

```
<tr v-for="(value, name) in width_nodes" :key="name">
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">{{ name }}</td>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm trying to mutate my props locally in my child component using a computed property and I want that property to update whenever the corresponding data in my parent changes.

Comment: I think the comment I was replying to disappeared.

Comment: Why do you need `localnodes`? Why not just use the  `nodes`  prop directly?

Comment: Not clear why do you need `localnodes` and there is need to use `Vue.set()` on a local `var widthnodes`.. However your code seems working properly. Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8sx9h?fontsize=14).. How do you output your `width_nodes`?

Comment: I used localnodes because of this answer: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/computed-property-not-updating/21148/6 Here LinusBorg says that a simple object passed via props isn't reactive, so you have to assign it to your data to make it reactive, if I understand correctly. I'll update my question with the infos you asked for.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Props are definitely reactive

Comment: Maybe the problem is in how you update the data in parent.

Comment: I fixed my issue by using an array instead of an object and using only instance methods of Array.prototype to mutate the array. Also some of my backend data source was faulty. I also don't do the localnodes bit anymore.